# Perl, HTML and MySQL where did my program break?

Tags: mysql, perl, error-handling, internal-server-error

Yes I am a student, yes this is an assignment but I just need some help clearing things up. I don't intend for someone to do my homework for me.

So I have a database with 5 books in it with 6 different columns of data. I'm trying to make a perl program that can search that database and return the results in tables. I have to add a way to add them to a cart but that will come later.

The problem with Perl is I have no idea how to check why I'm getting "Internal Server Error." The application makes it to the Perl page so I'm guessing its not that.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings; # allow for warnings to be sent if error's occur
use CGI qw( :standard ); # not a 100% sure what the rest of these mean but they are like #includs in C++, libraries for reference in the code
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql; #database data will come from mysql

my $dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:DATABASE NAME", "USERNAME", "PASS REMOVED" ) or
   die( "Could not make connection to database: $DBI::errstr" );   # connect to the database with address and pass or return error

   $term = $SEARCHTERM[]; #set the search char to $term

   $term =~ tr/A-Z/a-z/;  #set all characters to lowercase for convenience of search

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE %$term% OR Description LIKE %$term% OR Author LIKE %$term%" or die ("$term may have not worked");            #set the query string to search the database

   $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);  # prepare to connect to the database

   $sth->execute   # connect to the database
 or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";   #or return an error
 while (@data = $sth->fetchrow_array) {   #while we are grabbing he queried data do a table setup and set variables for table

print "<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\"> ";

    $title = $data[0];
    $desc = $data[1];
    $author = $data[2];
    $pub = $data[3];
    $isbn = $data[4];
    $photo = $data[5];

    print "<tr> <td width=50%>Title: $title</td> <td width=50% rowspan=5>$photo</td></tr><tr><td>Discreption Tags: $desc</td></tr><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td>Author: $author</td></tr><tr><td>ISBN: $isbn</td>
</tr></table> \n";



 }
```

Please help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not do code debugging. You need to do your own debugging and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the *relevant* code (if you post a wall of code then you haven't done enough debugging on your own) with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: It sounds like the real question is 'how do I track down a 501 error in a perl script?', which seems totally reasonable for SO.  Check your apache logs perhaps?

Comment: All CGI programs have to emit a header before printing anything else. The minimal header is `print "Content-type: text/html\n\n"`, but better use the `header` method from [CGI](https://metacpan.org/module/MARKSTOS/CGI.pm-3.63/lib/CGI.pm) — see the synopsis for an example. Should a `die` be executed, you'll find the message in the logs, while the client gets a 500

Answer (score 4):

Earlier, someone suggested,

```
my $sql = "
   SELECT *
     FROM Books
    WHERE Title LIKE '%$term%'
       OR Description LIKE '%$term%'
       OR Author LIKE '%$term%'
";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

Assuming he's right about your problem, that's incorrect. Consider what happens if someone is search for the title "Foo's Bar"...

Option 1:

```
my $sql = '
   SELECT *
     FROM Books
    WHERE Title LIKE '.$dbh->quote("%$term%").'
       OR Description LIKE '.$dbh->quote("%$term%").'
       OR Author LIKE '.$dbh->quote("%$term%").'
';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

Option 2:

```
my $sql = '
   SELECT *
     FROM Books
    WHERE Title LIKE ?
       OR Description LIKE ?
       OR Author LIKE ?
';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute("%$term%", "%$term%", "%$term%");
```

Answer (score 2):

First, may I also HIGHLY recommend adding `use strict;` to the top of the script and then fix the errors you will get, mostly declaring your variables with `my`.

Also may I suggest using a modern framework, like say [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us) rather than using the very outdated CGI module. They all can run under CGI-like environment and are FAR easier to use!

Finally, you should avoid interpolating variables into SQL strings since its a huge security risk! Try this site for more on the topic: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your select is invalid. Change

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE %$term% OR Description LIKE %$term% OR Author LIKE %$term%"
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Title LIKE '%$term%' OR Description LIKE '%$term%' OR Author LIKE '%$term%"'
```

Pattern literals for `LIKE` should be quoted.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about the syntax of those literals

Comment: Joel correctly added a link to http://bobby-tables.com/ in his answer. The code above may work, but nobody should ever use it.